# Select the first two items in each month for each person

Tags: sql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I want to get the first two items of each month for each person. The idea is if the item have the same date, it should return the largest amount instead. I am having trouble writing a simple logical condition for it.

**This is a screenshot of the table:**
[table datasource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qufAj.png)

The code should look something like this

```
SELECT MONTH(date) as month, name,  item (WHERE Top 3 MONTH(date))
FROM table
GROUP BY MONTH(date), name,  item
```

**The expected output should look something similar to this:**
[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDOuw.png)

(Edits): I'm sorry this is not for SQL server which I mislead the question with the hashtag. I am using phpmyadmin for SQL querying. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name, MONTH(date)
                                 ORDER BY date, quantity DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT date, name, item, quantity
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 2;
```

Comment: It says unrecognized statement type "With". I'm using the phpmyadmin. So right now I see the pattern of using OVER( PARTITION BY...). I'm not so familiar with it. Do you mind explain to me a bit in simple ways?

Answer (score 1):

When working with dates, you should *always* take the year into account, unless you explicitly want to combine data from multiple years into one row.  Nothing in your question suggests that the ultimate goal is to combine data from different time periods. So I would suggest:

```
SELECT YEAR(date) as year, MONTH(date) as month, name, item 
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date) ORDER BY date, quantity DESC) as seqnum
      FROM table t
     ) t
WHERE seqnum <= 2
ORDER BY MIN(date), name, item;
```

You could also explicitly limit the data to a single year.

Comment: This is actually really good to know thank you! Right now I think I am having problem updating the mysql server version to the latest one. I don't know why it just keep getting syntax error from everyone's code.

Comment: @chandler_liu . . . I'm a bit lost on your comment.  The question is tagged "sql-server".  All supported versions of SQL Server will run this code.

Comment: I think I made a mistake... It's not for SQL server... I thought the one I was working on is SQL server...

Comment: I'm using phpmyadmin. It said "Server version: 5.7.30 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)". So I just assume... Now I understand. SQL server is something specific made by Microsoft...

Answer (score 0):

You can use analytical function as follows:

```
select * from
(SELECT MONTH(date) as month, name, item, 
        row_number() 
          over (partition by MONTH(date), name order by date, quantity desc) 
        as rn
   FROM table) t
where rn <= 2
```

Comment: What does the t mean near the end?

Comment: And it appears to have error in line 4. "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by MONTH(sales_date) as sales_month, customer_id order by sales_date,' at line 4"

Comment: Error was due to as keyword in partition by. I have removed it and t is nothing but the alias given to the the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

The faster way to write this:

```
select top 2 with ties *
from [table]
order by row_number() over (partition by MONTH(date) as month, name order by date, quantity desc)
```